# Draw a pencil stoke using DrawLines() in android

Tags: android, draw, lines, stroke

There is an array 'a' which holds the points b/w which lines have to be drawn:

```
  float[] a = {0.0f, 1.2f, 3.4f, -9.87f, 65.4f, 0.0f, 567.9f};
  canvas.drawLines(a,mypaint);
```

Now what **drawLines(float[] pts, Paint paint)** does is that it draws a line b/w a[0], a[1] and a[2], a[3] and then the next line b/w a[4], a[5] and a[6], a[7].

> now I want a line b/w a[2], a[3] and a[4], a[5] as well.

So how to do that? Will **drawLines (float[] pts, int offset, int count, Paint paint)** help?? i dont understand the offset and count parameters? I wanted to use offset = -2 as parameter so that I a[2],a[3] are read twice.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawLines%28float%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Paint%29):

> public void drawLines (float[] pts, int offset, int count, Paint
> paint)
>
> offset    Number of values in the array to skip before drawing.
>
> count The
> number of values in the array to process, after skipping "offset" of
> them. Since

So to draw a line just between (a[2], a[3]) and (a[4], a[5]) you would call it like this:

```
canvas.drawlines(a, mypaint, 2, 4);
```

This skips `a[0],a[1]`, then begins taking pairs of two at `a[2],a[3]`, and finishes at `a[4],a[5]` (because each line uses 4 values, x, y pairs)

I did not see anything in the documentation about using negative offsets, but you should experiment and consider reading the source to find out. I don't think they are supported, though.

Comment: Thankyou for the response!
okay so after a[2],a[3], and [4],a[5] are done... what does  canvas.drawlines(a, mypaint, 2, 4); 
do next? Does it do a[4],a[5] and a[6],a[7]  next?

Comment: nope, it stops after it draws the line between a2,a3, and a4,a5.